# How to rename all partition columns in hive

Tags: hadoop, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning, apache-hive

When I am trying to rename all partition columns in an existing table for date range of one year which are partitioned - this is what I am getting.

`hive> ALTER TABLE test.usage PARTITION ('date') RENAME TO PARTITION (partition_date);`

`FAILED: ValidationFailureSemanticException Partition spec {partition_date=null} contains non-partition columns.`

I got that syntax from here: [1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RenamePartition%60)

Comment: could you please tell me what is the output for this command: > show create table test.usage; Also would be useful if you can share what Hive version you are using, Hive 0.13 there is an issue renaming partitions.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111036/how-to-alter-hive-partition-column-name/42252291#42252291

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that I am not 100% sure if what you want is to rename the value of the partition or actually change the column which the table is partitioned.

**Let's suppose you want to rename the partition's value.**

There is an issue in Hive 0.13 and in Hive 0.14 is working fine. Anyways, this should work:

```
set fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache=false; 
set fs.file.impl.disable.cache=false;
```

Now run the query by setting this property.

```
> hive> set fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache=false;  
> hive> set fs.file.impl.disable.cache=false;
> hive> ALTER TABLE test.usage PARTITION (date='oldValue') RENAME TO PARTITION (date='newValue');
```

**Let's suppose you want to change the partition column**

In this case what you will need to do is to recreate the table changing the column which the table will be partitioned.

Note: Remember that if you already had data inside the partitions, you will need to reinsert the data.

Please see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111036/how-to-alter-hive-partition-column-name/42252291#42252291)

Comment: Thank you!! Actually I am looking for a change of the partition column and this one helps.